# Direct sum of cyclic groups of integers modulo.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-sum

$\mathbb G = \mathbb Z_{p^3} \oplus\mathbb Z_{p^3}\oplus\mathbb Z_{p}$ - it's group, p - prime.

Find the number of decompositions of $\mathbb G$ into a direct sum of cyclic groups.

I found the number of elements in a group:
$p^3$ ---> $p^7 - p^6$ elements;
$p^2$ ---> $p^6 - p^3$ elements;
$p$ ---> $p^3 - 1$ elements;

Then i did this:
$\mathbb G = \mathbb A \oplus\mathbb B\oplus\mathbb C$ . Where exponent of A = $p^3$, exp of B = $p^3$ and exp of C = $p$.

For A we have  $ (p^7 - p^6)/(p^3 - p^2) = p^4 $ options.
For C we have $(p^3 - 1 - p^2 + 1)/(p-1) = p^2$ options. 
For $\mathbb B$, we must find the size of intersections of groups $\mathbb Z_{p^3}$ and $\mathbb Z_{p^3}$ in groups $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb Z_p$. And then do the same as in $\mathbb A$.

Result will be: $p^4 * p^2 * x$, where x = the number of options for B..

Question: how i can find the size of intersections of groups? If I have any mistakes, please tell me.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: $G$ is already a direct sum of cyclic groups, isn't it?

Comment: @Yanko I meant, that we need to find the number of decompositions of type $\mathbb A \oplus \mathbb B \oplus \mathbb C$.  Where  $\mathbb A \cong \mathbb Z_{p^3}$, $\mathbb B \cong \mathbb Z_{p^3}$, $\mathbb C \cong \mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: I think your calculation for $A$ is already off. There are $p^7-p^5$ elements of order $p^3$, so that should be the numerator. Next, when you want to choose $B$, you have to pick an element of order $p^3$, in such a way that $A\cap B=1$. Note that $A\cap B\neq 1$ if and only if  $A$ and $B$ have the same (unique) subgroup of order $p$. So count the number of elements of order $p^3$, then subtract the number of them such that their $p^2$th power is in $A^{p^2}$....

Comment: I don't think there's any more non-trivial decompositions of $G$. I mean, unless you replace the order of the direct sum there are no more because $\mathbb{Z}_{nm}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n\oplus \mathbb{Z}_m$ if and only if $n$ and $m$ are coprime.